# Kendo Grid - oData - Web API- Server Side Paging, Filtering - Decimal Type

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have set up the kendo grid with the following:

1. ASP.NET Web API with oDataController to read data using the oData formats.
2. Kendo grid with oData datasource with server side paging, filtering and sorting.

Everything works fine as expected except the filtering is not quite working with a column of decimal type. When using filtering on decimal type column, the kendo generates URL with the following filter value:

```
$filter=Value gt 0.5
```

The Web API returns Bad Request with the following:

```
{
  "odata.error":{
    "code":"","message":{
      "lang":"en-US","value":"A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.Decimal' and 'Edm.Double' for operator kind 'GreaterThan'."
    }
  }
}
```

If I take the URL and add 'M' at the end of 0.5 to explicitly specify type of decimal then it is working fine. Apparently when using Web API oData filtering, for some types such as decimal, double, datetime, you have to explicitly specify type in the URL as per this article: http://microliteorm.wordpress.com/2013/09/06/webapi-odata-filtering/

In terms of specifying column types in grid, there is only one type for numeric which is "number". It doesn't have different types for double, decimal, integer etc. How can I tell Kendo grid to specify the actual type (i.e. double, decimal etc.) in the URL when using filtering on "number" columns. Please note the filtering is working for datetime type. It's only an issue with numeric types.

EDIT: 
Found this article (Section No 6) on oData which specifies how primitive data types must be represented in URI  - http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/

Comment: Gah, running into this as well.  Did you figure out a work-around?  I'd hate to have to do some crazy string replaces or something to add an "m" to the end of my filter text.

Comment: I'm also stuck on this issue...

Answer (score 1):

Kendo UI does not support specific numeric data types like `int`, `float`, or `decimal`. In this framework, and JavaScript, all of these are simply numbers. Kendo provides `number` as a type abstraction that's useful for your understanding, not the browser's or server's interpreter.

As Jeremy hinted in his comment, you would have to replace the value of `0.5` with `0.5m` before sending it to the server. The [Kendo UI DataSource](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) provides just the method to do this.

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    //...other implementation details removed for brevity
    parameterMap: function(data, type) {
      if (type === 'read') {
        //...covert decimal values in the `data.filter` to strings ending with 'm'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than converting the data stream coming in, I feel, it might be more eficient and convenient to convert that filter, which will be a conversion for a unique item, once when it needs to be converted. 
For this, look into your ODATA wrapper, where it queries the source. It should have a state property which is passed in as argument, and that state property has a filter property, which itself is a tree of FilterDescriptor objects. You would want to manipulate these, rather than all your data.